# Change Excel error #N/A to 0 in set ranges, due to no data in database

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA code to change #N/A to 0 in set ranges does not work.

Workbook has a sheet for each day to the month, a button on each that runs macro to get data from a database PI System, based on the date on the sheet. Formulas pull the data for each hour. Trouble is when there is no data, like when the time changes to DST there is no 24th hour, it inserts error #N/A. Other macros insert this gathered data at other locations on the sheet, thus #N/As are carried over.

I want to change those #N/As to 0. My code is supposed to change only those #N/As, which is set ranges, to values first, then replace them with 0. I don't need to change the first location this data enters the sheet.

Part of my latest ChangeErrors() Sub is:

```
Range("C12:Z13").Copy
Range("C12:Z13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range("C12:Z13").Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:="0"
```

I have searched the questions that others have asked and found nothing that might help.

Comment: A reminder that `.Find()` and `.Replace()` work with the last used configuration of parameters. If `LookIn:=xlFormulas` is set, I don't think you'll find the value `#N/A`.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, it works for me. Does it produce an error message or...?

Try this instead of your 3rd line, though this will change all the #error messages , not just the #N/A errors:

```
Range("C12:Z13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).Value=0
```